# Magento layout.xml update with url helper - I always get an array instead of an url

Tags: magento

I want to insert a canonical meta tag in some sites which will be generated by an extension. So I inserted following code in the layout.xml of the extension:

```
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addLinkRel">
            <rel>canonical</rel>
            <href><url helper="core/url/getCurrentUrl"/></href>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

But I always just get "Array" instead of the url. What am I doing wrong?

If I will get it work, do I get just the `www.mystore.com/productxy.html` or the complete url with `www.mystore.com/productxy.html?page=3`.
Because I only need the first one, without the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost right. Though you can only use the `helper` attribute in layout xml on the tags directly under the `<action>` tag. Luckily, you mistakenly added the extra `<url>` tag, so this should work:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>canonical</rel>
        <href helper="core/url/getCurrentUrl"/>
    </action>
</reference>
```

`Mage_Core_Helper_Url::getCurrentUrl()` returns the `REQUEST_URI` from your `$_SERVER` variable. That variable includes the query, so unfortunately it's not as usable as you probably thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that. You're getting an `Array` because it's interpreting the `<url helper="core/url/getCurrentUrl"/>` XML node into an `Array`. This action processes the function `addLinkRel` instead and not the `<url />` helper at all (never).

The better (and much more fun) way of doing this is by creating a module where you can define a new block type that renders `<link rel='canonical' href='{$currentUrl}' />`.

Here's how I would do it, and it would take about 4 files:

#### app/code/community/Electricjesus/Canonical/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Electricjesus_Canonical>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Electricjesus_Canonical>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <canonical>
          <class>Electricjesus_Canonical_Block</class>
      </canonical>
    </blocks>    
  </global>
</config>
```

#### app/code/community/Electricjesus/Canonical/Block/Link.php

```
<?php
class Electricjesus_Canonical_Block_Link extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

}
```

#### app/design/frontend/base/default/template/canonical/link.phtml

```
<?php $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); ?>
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $currentUrl ?>" />
```

#### app/etc/modules/Electricjesus_Canonical.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Electricjesus_Canonical>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Electricjesus_Canonical>
  </modules>
</config>
```

So, the way to do it now here is (in your `local.xml`):

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="canonical/link" name="canonical_link" template="canonical/link.phtml" />
</reference>
```

So this is basically just a rough draft I cooked up in a few minutes, I've used the same solution for another kind of problem (but similar scope). So, give it a spin if you want.

Comment: This is way too long (I'm a newbie). Is it that hard to get the current URL of the resource in the layout XML file?